# Exclude first row from group

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a table with the cod number (REC_NUM) of all rows where is repeating columns ACCIDENT_REC_NUM and VEHICLE_REC_NUM. So I need to get the code from all rows that can be grouped by this two field.

This part is all right, you can check it by this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(REC_NUM)  FROM SEQUENCE_EVENT WHERE ACCIDENT_REC_NUM IN (
  SELECT ACCIDENT_REC_NUM
  FROM (
    select ACCIDENT_REC_NUM, VEHICLE_REC_NUM, COUNT(*) AS REPEAT  from SEQUENCE_EVENT
    GROUP BY ACCIDENT_REC_NUM, VEHICLE_REC_NUM
  )
  WHERE REPEAT > 1
)
```

So, now I have to exclude the first line of each group, because I just need the REC_NUM of the rows that are repeating, so the first one is ok.

Comment: No, sorry about it, It is a Oracle DB,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you determine which row is the "first" one in the group?

Assuming `REC_NUM` is unique and non-null on the `SEQUENCE_EVENT` table, you could do something like this, to exclude the row with the lowest value of REC_NUM for each group:

```
SELECT e.rec_num
  FROM sequence_event e
  JOIN ( SELECT MIN(c.rec_num) AS first_rec_num
              , c.accident_rec_num
              , c.vehicle_rec_num
          FROM sequence_event c
         GROUP
            BY c.accident_rec_num
             , c.vehicle_rec_num
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
       ) r
    ON r.accident_rec_num = e.accident_rec_num
   AND r.first_rec_num <> e.rec_num
```

---

Absent a sample of the resultset you expect to be returned, that's about all we can do. The original query is returning a single row with a count; so the query above does the same thing, except that it excludes some "first" row for each group from the count.

**EDIT**

Replaced `COUNT(e.rec_num)` with `e.rec_num` per OP comment. The query in this answer was modeled on the query in the OP question. The primary concern was demonstrating a pattern that addresses the question asked by OP.

Comment: Just perfect, the only thing that I had to change was the first line from SELECT COUNT(e.rec_num) to SELECT e.rec_num .

Thank you very much.

Comment: This is wrong. the Group By is only in the inner SELECT. so the main SELECT skipping only the rows whitch are the first in each group. but you should also add Group By and Having count(*) > 1 on the main SELECT

Comment: @EsterKaufman: This answer is not necessarily "wrong".  OP comment indicates that `COUNT(e.rec_num)` was replaced with `e.rec_num`, that same change is now made to the query in this answer. But either way, the query returns a resulset that satisfies one possible interpretation of a specification. The specification would better be illustrated by example data and sample output. But that wasn't provided by the OP. The query in OP question returns COUNT() , and the query in this answer was modeled on that. Its not necessarily wrong to return a single row COUNT; what matters is satisfying the spec.

Comment: I didn't mention the Count. pleaze read carefully my previous comment. I'm facing the same situation and I run your code but there is --2 problems--!! FIRST - the result contains rows that are unique in table, not having duplicates. SECOND - the ON statment should equals also with "vehicle_rec_num", as it appears in the Group By.

Comment: @EsterKaufman  - your comment says that "this is wrong" and says that the outer query requires a GROUP BY and a HAVING clause.  I did read your comment carefully. Your comment makes no mention of needing an additional condition in the ON clause. And this query does not require any of those things. This query satisfies a particular specification, and very likely the specification is significantly *different* than your specification. We can sling SQL constructs around and call things wrong. but again, what matters is satisfying the specification.

Comment: In the OP answer it says: I just need the REC_NUM of the rows that are --repeating--. Your code is wrongly return also rows whitch aren't repeating. My comment will warn someone who can failed notice to that.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly suggest that you do this with analytic functions.  I think the following does explicitly what you want:

```
select count(*)
from (select se.*,
             count(*) over (partition by accident_rec_num, vehicle_rec_num) as repeat,
             row_number() over (partition by accident_rec_num, vehicle_rec_num
                                order by rec_num) as seqnum
      from sequence_event se
     ) t
where repeat > 1 and seqnum > 1;
```

I am not 100% sure that this is the exact query, because I'm not sure about how the accident and vehicle numbers interact.

Comment: Update: works perfect!! and more important - the complexity of the query is much less that the accepted answer!